# Why can I not typecast T to another object in my comparator?

Tags: java, casting, comparator

I am trying to make a comparator that I can use to sort strings by their natural ordering.  I want the comparator to be generic so that I can pass through strings of from any class through it.

For example, I have a class `Name` which implements comparable such that the natural ordering of `Name` strings is by the length of the string.  However, there are situations where I want `Name` strings to instead be sorted by their natural order.  For that, I am writing a comparator below.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AlphabeticalOrderComparator implements Comparator<T> {

    public int compare(T obj1, T obj2) {

        Name name1 = (Name)obj1;
        Name name2 = (Name)obj2;

        return name1.name.compareTo(name2.name);
    }
```

The error I get with that code is that it tells me that T cannot be resolved to a type.  I believe the problem is with my typecasting from `T` to `Name`.

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this error?

Comment: "strings from any class"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: There are different types of classes I have.  I have a Names class, a Cars class, an employee class, etc.  Each one of those classes have their own strings, such as car model, employee name, etc.  I want to use a single comparator to sort the strings from all of those classes using the default ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T` is not even defined in your code.  You would've needed to write

```
class AlphabeticalOrderComparator<T> implements Comparator<T>
```

But even that doesn't make sense.  What this should be is

```
class AlphabeticalComparator implements Comparator<Name>
```

...because your `Comparator` only works for `Name`s anyway.

Comment: It only works for names, but I want it to work for other classes besides just names.  That is why I wanted to stick with generics T.  Is that even possible?  Do comparators only work for a single class?

Comment: @OmarN If you want it to work for other classes besides names, then why are you casting the arguments to `Name`?

Comment: @OmarN It sounds like you might want a `Named` interface, which forces any of its implementors to have a `getName()` method, and then you could write a `Comparator<Named>` that knows how to compare anything that has a name because it implements `Named`.

Comment: I see your point, and I see the flaw in my logic.  Thank you for pointing that out!